# keep reference to tabbar after viewDidUnload?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to disable all the tabs of a tab bar except the first tab. I came up with this code:

```
-(void)disableMainTabBar{

        [self setSelectedIndex:0];
        for(UITabBarItem *item in self.mainTabBar.items){
            if(self.firstTabBarItem != 0)  item.enabled = false;
            self.firstTabBarItem++;
        }
}
```

This code is in the UITabBarControllers class file.
Although this works when called from its own class when I call this function from another class it doesn't work. When I nslog the tabbar whenever the above method is called when this method gets called from another class its shows NULL. How can I make it keep a reference to the tabbar after viewDidUnload is called?

I'm new to iOS development so please bear with me.

Thanks!

-Shredder2794

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to import the `UITabBarController` class in the other class where you want to call the method and after creating it's instance call the method using that instance this will defiantly solved your problem of `NULL`.